# Are we as developers trying to put a square peg into a round hole with REST any other solutions?

Tags: rest, soap, xml-rpc

Recently I was tasked to take an old web service pre SOAP/REST era and bring it up to par with current web service "standards". It's pretty straight forward service, HTTP(s) POST XML, do stuff and respond with XML a very message oriented service.

The two most popular options for "web" services are SOAP and REST...

Though technically speaking SOAP would fit my application perfectly, it feels quite heavy handed and none of the WS-* features are really needed. I mean OK it does do SSL and simple username/password auth, but WS-*!@$@$@1!!! who needs it?! Well not me at least and my condolences for those who do (I'm sure in the right scenarios it's fine piece of technology ;))

Now I like REST because it's seems lite-weight. In fact I was able to take a very popular REST framework like Jersey and implement every single feature of the web service. In fact I managed to reduce the code base from thousands of lines of code to couple 100 lines of code. The obvious being lots of manual work was being done in the old service to parse the XML and map to the right function calls etc...

Whats wrong with REST?

On a high level? Nothing really (You can sit and argue the pros and cons till the cows come home). And this post/question isn't a flame war of SOAP vs REST. But why is it that most chose to go down this route?

Though I was able to implement 100% of the service using Jersey and REST I pretty much managed to break all the rules of "REST" if there are any.

- It doesn't serve named resources
- It's not cacheable
- It's more complex then CRUD
- Everything is a POST
- Everything is returned as 200 OK

But it works fantastic! :) But I'm breaking the rules :P

One example, my app has hundreds of "error" codes. The REST guys like to say map to 400 Bad Request and put your reason in the body. But I say why bother when I can just simply return the code in the XML response. Why confuse the client (Developer), when they can simply parse one code?

So if SOAP is heavy and REST seems more oriented for CRUD and resource oriented type of applications, what are the options for lite-weight "web" services? XMLRPC? Why are people square pegging into REST or did I miss something?

Let the fun begin! :)

Comment: What you're doing is even REST at all, forget "break all the rules". You're really just using HTTP. If you're OK with that, then so be it. Use what works for you...

Comment: Let me rephrase that NOT only CRUD.

Comment: This is the definition of [Not Constructive](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) =)

Comment: My scenario wasn't the same as you -- my protocol was defined for me to be less than what Microsoft's SOAP web services provided -- but I came up with [my own "web service" approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2817637/256431) that only used Microsoft's ASP.NET HTTP and VB's Axis XML implementations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy re-inventing a tried and tested distributed application protocol like HTTP then feel free.

- If you conform to HTTP, then new developers will get up to speed on how it works much 
  quicker.
- If you conform to HTTP then you can reuse existing components like debugging tools,  caching proxies, load balancers.
- Your application gains the benefits of years of real world testing.

Comment: Not re-inventing! In fact just upgrading pre REST/SOAP service. I technically like the goodness of REST I just don't need most of it. Don't need caching, no proxies. It's a business service not a resource service. Clients connect on demand and execute complex business processes. It's not serving resources. There's no real requirement for PUT vs POST or GET. Failures are "soft" failures. Etc...