# xml response http post - convert request.inputstream to string - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm receiving an xml response and I now want to parse this.

Currently what I have to receive the XML response is:

```
    Dim textReader = New IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream)

    Request.InputStream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    textReader.DiscardBufferedData()

    Dim Xmlin = XDocument.Load(textReader)
```

How can I go ahead now a process this and pick out the element values?

```
<subscription>
<reference>abc123</reference>
<status>active</status>
<customer>
    <fname>Joe</fname>
    <lname>bloggs</lname>
    <company>Bloggs inc</company>
    <phone>1234567890</phone>
    <email>joebloggs@hotmail.com</email>
 </customer>
 </subscription>
```

If I have it in string format I can do this using

```
    Dim xmlE As XElement = XElement.Parse(strXML) ' strXML is string version of XML

    Dim strRef As String = xmlE.Element("reference")
```

Do I need to convert the request.inputstream to a strign format or is there another better way?

Thanks

Comment: Use XmlDocument.  With it, you can call its [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807) method with the url and it'll pull it all down nicely.  [Read more...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kza7w4k)

Comment: Not only XmlDocument but once you get it into that, you can use LINQ to get the data, possibly even faster.

Comment: However, I'm compelled to ask why you're receiving it like this, because we can certainly receive it as typed XML if you like

Comment: Hi, A bit unsure...I'm receiving it as a http post response. Looked at this question and seemed like the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816168/receive-xml-via-post-with-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end after much testing I could only get this to work:

```
    Dim textReader = New IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream)

    Request.InputStream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    textReader.DiscardBufferedData()

    Dim Xmlin = XDocument.Load(textReader)

    Dim strXml As String = Xmlin.ToString

    Dim xmlE As XElement = XElement.Parse(strXml)
    Dim strRef As String = xmlE.Element("reference")
    Dim strStatus As String = xmlE.Element("status")
    Dim strFname As String = xmlE.Element("customer").Element("fname").Value()
    Dim strLname As String = xmlE.Element("customer").Element("lname").Value()
    Dim strCompany As String = xmlE.Element("customer").Element("company").Value()
    Dim strPhone As String = xmlE.Element("customer").Element("phone").Value()
    Dim strEmail As String = xmlE.Element("customer").Element("email").Value()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to convert the request.inputstream to a strign format or is there another better way?

You could directly load it from the request stream, you don't need to convert it to a string:

```
Request.InputStream.Position = 0
Dim Xmlin = XDocument.Load(Request.InputStream)
Dim reference = Xmlin.Element("subscription").Element("reference").Value
```

or:

```
Dim reference = Xmlin.Descendants("reference").First().Value
```

Comment: Yes, that was the point of my original solution as linked to by the OP!

Comment: Specifically I wanted to use VB.NET's axis queries: `xmlIn.<subscription>.<reference>`.